# switching functions depending on #define

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

i have a piece of code where is something like this happening

```
     type<X> function( args<x> g)
     {
        ...
        function2();
        .....
     }
```

now X can be of two types say type1 and type2. i want to write the function as 
         type function( args g)
         {
            ...

```
        if X is of type1 then call function2();
        if X is of type2 then call function3();
        .....
     }
```

how can i achieve this. i am wrting in C++ and developing in visual studio.

thanks

Comment: What kind of language is this? And where is the #define?

Comment: @JohnB C-style pseudo-code, probably.

Comment: I smell template specialization

Comment: Wouldn't real code be better?

Comment: What does this have to do with `#define`? Why did you mention `#define` in the question title?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either *template specialization* or *function overload*. For example:

```
template <class X>
int foo(std::vector<X> a)
{
  foo1(); 
}

template <>
int foo<int>(std::vector<int> a)
{
  foo2(); 
}
```

Note, if you need to specialize your function only for a few types, it is better to use function overload. If you have a lot of similar code, and the only difference is in 1 function call, one might use `typeid`:

```
if (typeid(X) == typeid(type1)) {
  function2()
} else if (typeid(X) == typeid(type2)) {
  function3()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Note:  code that compares based on type is usually an indication of a poor design.

You could use one function that has different signatures:

```
void my_function(const type_1& t1);
void my_function(const type_2& t2);
```

Let the compiler choose the function base on the parameter type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that X is a class? You should use virtual functions and created a derived version of X. See below example:

```
class X
{
public:
    virtual void myFunction(int input) { // do stuff here... }
};

class Y : public X
{
public:
    void myFunction(int input) { // do overridden stuff here... }
};
```

Then, if you create an object of type X and call myFunction() on it, then it will run the "do stuff here" code. If you create an object of type Y and call myFunction() on it, then it will run the "do overridden stuff here" code instead. But you can use whatever object you create in a polymorphic fashion, like so:

```
X *obj = NULL;

if (condition met)
{
    obj = new X();
}
else
{
    obj = new Y();
}

obj->myFunction(myInput); // will call either X or Y's myFunction() depending on what type it is
```